# Sort JSONB array of strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column which contains strings with jsonb type, for example:

```
["Stomach Mixed Adenocarcinoma", "Gastric Mixed Adenocarcinoma", "Mixed Breast Carcinoma"]
```

And I have the following query which gets 'search' as a parameter and returns entities based on similarity with search pattern.

```
with names as (
      select b.id, b.name, b.synonyms,
             case
                 when b.id = :search then 0
                 else 1 - similarity(s.disease_name, :search)
                 end as distance
        from disease_registry b
        cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(
                        b.synonyms || jsonb_build_array(b.name)
                ) as s(disease_name)
       where (similarity(s.disease_name, :search) > 0.2
           or b.id = :search
           or :search = '')
  )

select n.id, n.name, n.synonyms
  from names n
 group by n.id, n.name, n.synonyms
 order by (case
               when n.name ilike '%' || :search || '%'
                   then 0
               else min(n.distance)
     end),
          n.name
```

Now i want to sort the synonym array based on similarity with search pattern, and only after that return the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
  with names as (
  select b.id,
         b.name,
         b.synonyms,
         case
             when b.id = :search then 0
             else 1 - similarity(s.disease_name, :search)
             end as distance
    from disease_registry b
    cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(
                b.synonyms || jsonb_build_array(b.name)
            ) as s(disease_name)
   where (similarity(s.disease_name, :search) > 0.2
       or b.id = :search
       or :search = '')


)

    select n.id,
           n.name,
           (
               select jsonb_agg(elem order by similarity(elem::text, :search) desc)
                 from jsonb_array_elements_text(n.synonyms) as elem
           ) as synonyms
      from names n
     group by n.id, n.name, n.synonyms
     order by (case
                   when n.name ilike '%' || :search || '%'
                       then 0
                   else min(n.distance)
         end),
              n.name;
```

This is how I achieved it.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.